# is it acceptable to store 800x1067 pixels image (about 270 kb) into sqlite/Core Data?

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I'm writing an app that will store a bunch of records with images attached. I'm thinking in define 800x1067 pixels (about 270 kb) size's image.

Is reasonable to store this kind of images into a SQLite database? I guess will be hundreds of records into this table.

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can (it's acceptable), but when I experimented with this, I found SQLite to be much too slow. There's a serious performance hit for storing images in SQLite. I now store images in a custom directory structure in the app's Documents folder, and just store references to those filenames in SQLite. I know some people happily store thumbnails in SQLite (even with thumbnail images you'll get a performance hit, though it's negligible for these small images), but personally I put all images in my Documents folder.

For the sake of testing performance, I tested loading images using `imageWithContentsOfFile` versus reading the image from Core Data and loading it into a `UIImage` using `imageWithData`, and retrieving 10,000 thumbnails from Documents took 12.988 seconds on an iPhone 4S and doing it from Core Data took 23.743 seconds. (And, obviously, if you use your own `NSCache` and/or `imageNamed`, it's *much* quicker if you happen to retrieve the same image occasionally.) While this admittedly is Core Data benchmark, when I tried using sqlite (via FMDB) a few months back with larger images, the difference between sqlite and `imageWithContentsOfFile` was appreciable.

Comment: I will store images in a custom directory structure in the app's Documents folder like you said. Thanks Robert !